# recyclerview fill with getter setter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

is it possible to setCoordinate in viewHolder than getCoordinate in other layout? can i get an example for it? here my viewHolder example:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {
//views

ImageView mImageIv;
TextView mTitleTv, mDescrTv;

ItemClickListener itemClickListener;



myHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    this.mImageIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Model_ImageIv);
    this.mDescrTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Model_DescrTv);
    this.mTitleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Model_TitleTv);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
}
public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic){
    this.itemClickListener =  ic;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by saying "setCoordinate"? 
Do you mean you need to know Y position of a particular View relative to parent RecyclerView?

Comment: i mean adding getter setter inside viewholder...

Answer (score 0):

You can add any methods to your ViewHolder.

Then you can use:

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
```

or

```
recyclerView.findContainingItemView(view);
recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position);
recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(id);
```

to find ViewHolder and call `getCoordinate()`

Answer (score 0):

This operations used to be managed from the adapter that holds the complete set of data. You could update the item you want and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method.